# Facebook release key_hash

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have problem with generate key hash.
I make 2 key:

```
C:\openssl\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias forumurology -keystore uroweb7228.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
Enter keystore password:  *******
c/6e5fY8Rg3Gshn1TKucia***/A=

C:\openssl\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias a
ndroiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
Enter keystore password:  android
3L0oeMh7uk9YWE0sYavUuT***yU=
```

then save it to my facebook application settings.
When i run release .apk, i have error:

```
10-21 16:48:11.583: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(20097): Exception during service
10-21 16:48:11.583: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(20097): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash ypC1--aybTSQXdzXGLtM-_nXydI does not match any stored key hashes.
10-21 16:48:11.583: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(20097):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
```

Comment: Why not just use the key hash from the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the device is creating a new key hash which is not in your app settings. So you have to update the keyhash accordingly.. Use this in onCreate()

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```